# How To Disable A Select Collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character with 2 2D Colliders in Unity, one for the head, and one for the feet. How do I Disable only the Head Collider in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public Collider2D headCollider;  // drag and drop head collider to this in inspector.

void DisableHeadCollider()
{
    headCollider.enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your character prefab following this structure :

- Character (game object)

  - Head   (game object with a Box Collider 2D)
  - Feet   (game object with a Box Collider 2D)

Then, in your character class, you can access your body elements using code this way :

```
this.transform.FindChild("Head"); //will give you the head transform
this.transform.FindChild("Head").GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>(); // will give you the box collider component
this.transform.FindChild("Head").GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().gameObject.SetActive(false); // desactivate the box collider 2D
```